# Working on small objects in MM but Add menu adds relatively giant objects

Tags: scale

I'm Working on small objects in MM but the Add menu adds relatively giant objects compared to scale I am working. I can't figure out how to get them down to size and when I zoom out I cannot see new object.
Is there a way to tell Blender to add a new object in a smaller initial size?

Answer (score 1):

After adding new object press <kbd>F6</kbd> and set acceptable size or radius of the object.

Next time, during session, then you add same object, blender will remember that size.